# Missing CSV Export button in Influxdb 2.7 Data Explorer

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I recently upgraded my Influxdb instance from 2.61 to 2.7, but the CSV export button in the Data Explorer is no longer displayed. I didn't see anything in the changelog, and I wasn't able to find it relocated to somewhere else.

[image]

Has this feature been removed, or am I missing something?

Comment: I see the same question on influxdata community forum: https://community.influxdata.com/t/export-to-csv-in-version-2-7-0-missing/29450

The reply from Anaisdg doesn't offer any positive hope that its removal was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when using HTTP, switched to HTTPS and the button reappeared.